# Custom cordova plugin returns Cordova is not defined error in Ionic3

Tags: cordova, ionic3

I am using my customized plugin originally written for phonegap in ionic3 as :

```
cordova.plugins.swrve.event(this.successCallback(), this.errorCallback());
```

But getting error as  "cordova is not defined".  How can i use this plugin in ionic3 as its a customized plugin i installed.

Anyone help will appreciated .

Comment: are you calling within `this.platform.ready().then(()=>{})`?

Comment: Yes already using the same thing, I am calling in the device ready.